# Jest testing window.scroll listener

Tags: reactjs, scroll, jestjs

I have a window scroll event listener attached via addEventListener. It just add extra movies to page when the page bottom i reached.
I am trying to test it using jest. But i can't figure out a proper way. Either i get a test passing ok, but don't have code coverage for the lines of function that handles scroll.
Here is my component in react (i removed extra pieces that is tested ok):

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch, shallowEqual } from 'react-redux';

import { apiPathUpdated, selectQuery } from '../../modules/query/index';
import {
  selectMovies, loadMovies, addMovies, addCurrentMovieTrailerKey,
} from '../../modules/movies/index';
import { loadGenres, selectGenres } from '../../modules/genres/index';
import { updateStatus, selectStatus } from '../../modules/status/index';
import { genreFilterUpdated, selectGenreId } from '../../modules/filters/index';

import SearchResultsPage from './SearchResultsPage';

const SearchResultsPageContainer = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset === document.body.clientHeight) {
        page += 1; //this line stays uncovered
        fetchUrl = getFetchUrl(searchQuery, page); //this line stays uncovered
        dispatch(addMovies(fetchUrl)); //this line stays uncovered
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    if (page * pageSize >= movies.length && movies.length !== 0) {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      dispatch(updateStatus('loaded'));
    }

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, [apiPath, searchQuery, genreId]);

  return (
    <SearchResultsPage {...bunch of props}/>
  );
};

export default SearchResultsPageContainer;
```

And here is my jest test fro the component (i also removed extra test case so get rid of some mess):

```
import React from 'react';
import ShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';
import SearchResultsPageContainer from '../index';

let mockQuerySlice;
let mockGenres;
let mockMovie;
let mockMovies;
let mockMoviesSlice;
let mockFiltersSlice;
let mockStatusSlice;
let mockUseSelector;
let triggerMockUseSelector;
let renderer;
let result;

const map = {};
window.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
  map[event] = cb;
});
const spy = jest.spyOn(window, 'addEventListener');

beforeEach(() => {
  renderer = new ShallowRenderer();
  renderer.render(<SearchResultsPageContainer />);
  result = renderer.getRenderOutput();
});

afterEach(() => {
  renderer = null;
  result = null;
});

describe('render SearchResultsPage component', () => {
  it('handles window.scroll event correctly', () => {
    map.scroll();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I tried to use [this solution](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/testing-global-event-listener-within-a-react-component-b9d661e59953), but it doesn't make necessary code lines covered. (I feel like i missed something, but i can't figure what)

Comment: Did you try adding wait or waitFor methods after map.scroll()? You probably need to wait for your spy to have been called.

Comment: Thanks for comment.
If i understood correctly. I have added `await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));` right after map.scroll().
The thing is that tests passes ok even without this line. i just don't get jest code coverage for those three lines.